# Default diagram for Toolbox

Tags: enterprise-architect

I have a custom toolbox with a `foo` element.

I would like the `foo` to be green on an class diagram and red on flow chart diagram by default.

Adding more than one stereotype to non- UML type is impossible (as far as I know).

Is it possible to create 2 toolboxes- one for class diagrams and one for flow charts, specifying the default diagram for each toolbox in the profile?

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the way you describe it.

Toolboxes don't specify which diagram they open, it's the other way around: you create a custom diagram type and associate it with a toolbox. Different custom diagrams may use the same custom toolbox.

You can create two custom diagram types, one for class ("Logical") and one for flow chart ("Activity"), but if you're only after getting the same stereotyped element (`foo`) to display differently in the diagrams, you don't need to.

The solution is to create a shape script for the stereotype, which checks the diagram type and changes the color accordingly. The diagram type can be queried from the shape script using the `diagram.type` property (for the base UML diagram type), or `diagram.mdgtype` (for the custom diagram type, if you've defined one). There is no need to create an Add-In, as another answer suggests, at least not in EA 11.

Check the help file under Extending UML Models -- MDG Technology SDK -- Shape Scripts -- Write Scripts -- Display Element/Connector Properties.

A simple script might look like this:

```
shape main {
    if (hasproperty("diagram.type", "Logical")) {
        setfillcolor(0, 255, 70);
    } else if (hasproperty("diagram.type", "Activity")) {
        setfillcolor(255, 87, 87);
    }
    drawnativeshape();
};
```

Comment: Shame on me. I'm getting too old. I missed `diagram.type`

Comment: @Uffe, Thanks a lot. I would like to use your suggestion for extending  shape scripts of elements, but non UML types (elements from other MDGs, such as ArchiMate types) cannot be extended AFAIK. Do you know if it is impossible indeed?

Comment: Yes, it is. Check the help file under Extending UML Models -- MDG Technology SDK -- Developing Profiles -- Create Stereotype Profiles -- Create Stereotypes Extending non-UML Objects.

Comment: @Uffe, GREAT! One more question please: ` drawnativeshape();` caused the non-UML elements to change their shape to their parent shape. I would like the shape to remain as the non UML element. If I omit the ` drawnativeshape();`, the shape is got invisible. Any ideas?

Comment: Use drawparentshape(). This is intended for exactly that situation, but the question didn't mention the non-UML requirement.

Comment: @Uffe, The question does not include the issue since I didn't know that your solution differs between UML and non UML types. Using `drawparentshape()` indeed draws the extended shape, but without any color. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

No. You need to have two different stereotypes. The target diagram is independent of the element. If you want the element appear different on the type of the diagram where you use it you need to adapt the shape script so it calls an add-in which detects the diagram type.

Well, writing the last sentence I would not know how to detect the diagram where the element in question is in. Needs investigation. But other than that - no solution I know of.

**Edit**: Since the add-in just receives the element GUID it has no way to figure out the diagram from where the call is made. Probably worth a feature request. But the time where we saw those realized in the next build are gone (since more than 10 years).

A last though: template packages. I almost never used them. Maybe they offer coloring depending on diagram/element.

**Edit2**: Last resort EA_OnPostNewDiagramObject. Catch that and you can get all information you need to apply the color.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Using template package is a good idea: I try to drag class element on 2 different diagrams, with different color. The result is disappointing: no affect to diagram type, the element is colored always the same. So what in the world is the template package purpose???

Comment: As said: I don't use them. There is probably a use case for template packages but like so many "features" in EA: only the programmer who invented it really knows. (see my edit regarding add-in)

Comment: @user3165438 The template package will look at the first diagramobject for an element of certain type/stereotype and will copy most of its features (appearance, notes, ...) to newly created elements of that type/stereotype. As such it is an easy, quick way to set an element template without the need for any add-ins or scripts.

Comment: @GeertBellekens, Thanks for the details. Can I set different color for element depending on diagram type, using a template package? It seems like not.

Comment: @user3165438 No, I don't think so. It also seems a bit weird to make the distinction based on the diagram type. I would rather think in terms of elements, not in terms of diagrams. Changing the appearance of an element based on its type or stereotype make a lot more sense, and it is supported by both the template package and profiles/MDG's